# New To Java, Can't figure out to use a while loop to end user input

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and i'm currently trying to make a while loop that will loop if the user inputs Yes. Also i want it it to prompt the user to input "endinput" if they instead put Stop. Any ideas? Just started Java programming and this is stumping me as I can't figure how to do continue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[]
        title=new String[100],
        author=new String[100],
        publisher=new String[100],
        ISBN=new String[100],
        endinput=new String[100];
        boolean Stop = false;
        boolean Yes = true;
        double[] price=new double[100];

        System.out.println("Welcome To Kieran's Bookstore");

        System.out.println("Input The Title:");
        title[0] = scan.next(); 
        System.out.println("Input The Author:");
        author[0] = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Input The Price Of The Book:");
        scan.next();
        System.out.println("Input The Publisher:");
        publisher[0]= scan.next();
        System.out.println("Input The ISBN:");
        ISBN[0]=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(Yes/Stop)");
        scan.next();

        while(!Stop)
            {
            System.out.println("Input The Title:");
            title[0] = scan.next(); 
            System.out.println("Input The Author:");
            author[0] = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Input The Price Of The Book:");
            scan.next();
            System.out.println("Input The Publisher:");
            publisher[0]= scan.next();
            System.out.println("Input The ISBN:");
            ISBN[0]=scan.next();
            System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(Yes/Stop)");
            scan.equals(Stop);
        }
        while (!Stop) {System.out.println("Please Type 'endinput':");
          scan.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Please Type 'endinput':");
        scan.next();
        if (scan.equals("endinput"))System.exit(0);
        scan.close();
```

Comment: What is `scan.equals(Stop)` supposed to do ?

Comment: its supposed to prompt the user to enter 'endinput' as they would like to stop the program. is that not what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use one `while` to achieve that
. Assign a variable to the `scan.next()` and do the checking using `if`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] title = new String[100], author = new String[100], publisher = new String[100], ISBN = new String[100],
            endinput = new String[100];
    // boolean Stop = false;
    boolean Yes = true;
    double[] price = new double[100];

    while (Yes) {
        System.out.println("Welcome To Kieran's Bookstore");
        System.out.println("Input The Title:");
        title[0] = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Input The Author:");
        author[0] = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Input The Price Of The Book:");
        scan.next();
        System.out.println("Input The Publisher:");
        publisher[0] = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Input The ISBN:");
        ISBN[0] = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(Yes/Stop)");
        String ans = scan.next();
        if (ans.equals("endinput") || (ans.equals("Stop"))) {
            Yes = false;
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you John I don't know what you did but I appreciate it

Comment: Btw I would suggest to follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod(...)`, `FirstWordUpperCaseClass` and `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`

Comment: @KieranFleming What is not clear to you ? Between, consider mark this as answer if this helped.

Comment: how do you mark questions as answered? as what you did worked

Comment: There have a check mark beside the answer,just click that

Comment: ohhhhh, god i'm dumb XD